# Intermittent starting

Tags: electrical, starting, hyundai, intermittent-problems, elantra

My 09 Hundai Elantra have an intermittent starting problem after a few cranks and a few minutes wait it eventually starts .appears to be worst when the engine is hot. On going problem for the past two years.

Comment: What has the mechanic at your local service shop said about it when you put it in for service?

Comment: Are there any check engine codes?  I would start by verifying the intake air temperature and coolant temperature sensor readings make sense by monitoring those PIDs with a decent scan tool.